# Starting intent without a new bundle

Tags: android, class, android-activity, android-intent, resume

I have a which is a list click method that starts a new activity and gives it a bundle

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l , View v, int position, long id){
  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


  Intent lis = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
  stopService(lis);  

  Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
  String songpen = o.toString();
  String artwork = albumartwork.get(songtitle.indexOf(songpen));
  String artistpen = artistname.get(songtitle.indexOf(songpen)); 
  String albumpen = albumname.get(songtitle.indexOf(songpen));
  String pathpen = path.get(songtitle.indexOf(songpen));

  int songpos = songtitle.indexOf(o);

    Intent i  = new Intent(IplayerActivity.this, SongPlaying.class);
    i.putExtra("songnamekeyword", songpen);
    i.putExtra("artistkeyword", artistpen);
    i.putExtra("albumkeyword", albumpen);
    i.putExtra("pathkeyword", pathpen);
    i.putExtra("artworkkeyword", artwork);

    i.putExtra("position", songpos);

    i.putExtra("nextsong", songtitle);
    i.putExtra("nextartist", artistname);
    i.putExtra("nextalbum", albumname);
    i.putExtra("nextpath", path);
    i.putExtra("nextartwork", albumartwork);

    startActivity(i);
```

}

I want to create a Now Playing bundle which starts the Songplaying class with the exact same information as it already had... Basically i want to just resume the class as it was without changing anything.  But when i do this

```
             Intent k = new Intent(this, SongPlaying.class);        
            startActivity(k);
```

I get an error.  I just want to reload the SongPlaying class with information it already had previously.

```
11-28 15:46:50.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(817): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 15:46:50.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(817): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service unjustentertainment.com.MusicService: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-28 15:46:50.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(817):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2969)
11-28 15:46:50.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(817):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-28 15:46:50.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(817):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2087)
11-28 15:46:50.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(817):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-28 15:46:50.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(817):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-28 15:46:50.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(817):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-28 15:46:50.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(817):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 15:46:50.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(817):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-28 15:46:50.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(817):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-28 15:46:50.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(817):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-28 15:46:50.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(817):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-28 15:46:50.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(817): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-28 15:46:50.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(817):     at unjustentertainment.com.MusicService.onCreate(MusicService.java:36)
11-28 15:46:50.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(817):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2959)
```

My music service class needs a path to play the media player.  but with this new intent im not adding any extras because i simply want to display SongPlaying class exactly as it was before i clicked the Now Playing Button

Comment: Please post details about the error you are facing. The second way should work, you probly just get a NullPointerException when trying to access an extra that's not supplied or somthing along these lines.

Comment: 11-28 15:46:28.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(787): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{unjustentertainment.com/unjustentertainment.com.SongPlaying}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-28 15:46:28.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(787):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)

Comment: Yes as expected a NullPointerException. Please edit the full stacktrace and the piece of code where it points to into the question. :)

Comment: check the edits i added the stuff

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not checking if the bundle hasExtra inside your onCreate method in IplayerActivity.this

Otherwise, you need to include more information because it's difficult to tell where your NPE is coming from.

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Sets Content View to Main
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        if(Integer.parseInt(VERSION.SDK) > 3){
          new Airpush(getApplicationContext(), "25528","airpush",true,true,true);
         }
       
        updatelist();
        
        
    }

Comment: I suspect updatelist holds the answer. What's the line where the NPE occurs?

Comment: Basically i have a mediaplayer which displays album cover and songname and stuff and when i click the now playing button i want to go baack to the songplaying class which displays these textviews i just want to redisplay them as they already were before the user went back to the list of songs

Comment: Just store this data in preferences, the database, or the file system.